# How to get response data of XMLHttpRequest in Shift-jis

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I use XMLHttpRequest .

If data is written in UTF-8 there is no ploblem.

But data is written in Shift-jis I can’t read response.

I tried to set Request header like bellow but it didn’t work.

setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=Shift-JIS");

How can I get response data in Shift-JIS?

Comment: Not sure, but would `XHR.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=shift-jis')` help?

Comment: I tried but nothing Chaned.I add xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=shift-jis") both befor sending request and after geting request.

Answer (score 0):

Internal representation of JavaScript string is UTF-16. So you will convert Shift-JIS byte array to JavaScript string first.

Modern browsers can use TextDecoder (https://caniuse.com/#feat=textencoder) for this purpose. First, you will have to set `responseType` of `XMLHttpRequest` to `arraybuffer`:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
var arrayBuffer = req.response;
```

You will get a byte array that represents the response data in Shift-JIS encoding in `arrayBuffer`.

Then, make a `Uint8Array` object for `Shift-JIS` text, and convert it to an ordinal JavaScript string.

```js
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
var decoder = new TextDecoder('shift_jis');
var str = win1251decoder.decode(byteArray);
```

You will get an UTF-16 string in `str`.